# Nuxt3 and Pinia - Cannot find module '\.output\server\node_modules\pinia\dist\pinia'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I've just installed Pinia in my Nuxt3 project and in development mode works everything and when I try to access my application in production mode I got this error and the website freeze.

```
[h3] [unhandled] H3Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pavel\Documents\GitHub\eway\website\.output\server\node_modules\pinia\dist\pinia' imported from C:\Users\pavel\Documents\GitHub\eway\website\.output\server\chunks\server.mjs
    at createError (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:196:15)
    at nodeHandler (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:386:21)
    at async ufetch (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
    at async $fetchRaw2 (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/ohmyfetch/dist/chunks/fetch.mjs:131:20)
    at async Object.errorhandler [as onError] (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:321:16)
    at async nodeHandler (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:394:9)
    at async ufetch (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
    at async $fetchRaw2 (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/ohmyfetch/dist/chunks/fetch.mjs:131:20)
    at async Object.errorhandler [as onError] (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:321:16)
    at async nodeHandler (file:///C:/Users/pavel/Documents/GitHub/eway/website/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:394:9) {
  statusCode: 500,
  fatal: false,
  unhandled: true,
  statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error'
}
```

Here is my store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useNavbarStore = defineStore({
    id: 'navbarStore',
    state: () => {
        return {
            menu: false
        }
    },
    actions: {
        toggleMenu() {
            this.menu = !this.menu
        }
    }
})
```

And here is how I use it in the component:

```
<script>
import { useNavbarStore } from '~/store/navbar'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            store: useNavbarStore()
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getLink(to) {
            let baseLink = '/';
            return baseLink + to
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: do you have a build step? it's odd that in "production" mode there's references to `file:///` path

Comment: Probably missing a dev server, since you cannot work with the `file` protocol.

Comment: @kissu what dev server you think is missing?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have a build step, I've just used this [link](https://codybontecou.com/nuxt3-and-pinia.html#vuex-pinia) to add pinia to nuxt3

Comment: so, how do you go from "dev" to "production"? Did your code work "in production" before you added pinia?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, my code worked before in production mode and after I've added pinia it gives me that error message when I try to run it.

Comment: You're using a CDN or something alike? For dev and production, you should anyway: use Vite. Not sure how it worked so far, but it was more luck than anything (or quite a simple project IMO).

Comment: I think that nuxt3 is already using Vite for dev and production. And I am not using a cdn.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/piniajs/example-nuxt-3/issues/50